# tf.trainable_variables returns more than one graph's variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to write my own multi-gpu on one node tensorflow example.

I read the code here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py

The core code of mine is:

```
vars = tf.trainable_variables()
grads = tf.gradients(cost, vars)
tower_grads.append(grads)
```

But as the program run to the second GPU, `tf.trainable_variables()` return both the first round of the loop tensorflow varibles and the second round's tensorflow varibles.

By the way, I think this task is that the two GPU use the same variables, but the gradients is different. Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

The variable is named `aaa` in the first round.

But the variable is named `aaa_1` in the second round. Even if I set `reuse = True`.

The solution is using `tf.get_variable` instead of `tf.Variable`

I learn it from https://github.com/normanheckscher/mnist-multi-gpu/blob/master/mnist_multi_gpu_batching_train.py#L356